# Task scheduler. VBS script is not being executed

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, outlook, scheduled-tasks

I've created a vbs to retrieve the attachments from Outlook unread emails and store them into a folder.

**GetMail.vbs**

```
Dim SavePath
Dim Subject
Dim FileExtension
Dim k

SavePath = "D:\IN\"
Subject = "'Replication IN'"

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6) 'Inbox

Set colItems = objFolder.Items
Set colFilteredItems = colItems.Restrict("[Unread]=true")
Set colFilteredItems = colFilteredItems.Restrict("[Subject] = " & Subject)


For k = colFilteredItems.Count to 1 step -1
  set objMessage  = colFilteredItems.Item(k)
  intCount = objMessage.Attachments.Count
    If intCount > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To intCount
                objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile SavePath &  _
                    objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).FileName
        Next
        objMessage.Unread = False
    End If
Next
```

Now, I've to automatize this task and once done, execute another program which will process the received attachments. To do that, I've created a batch file.

**MyBatch.bat**

```
cls
@ECHO OFF
ECHO. *  Retrieving emails ... *
"D:\GetMail.vbs"
ECHO. *  Importing data. Please wait ... *
"D:\MyProgram.exe" 
CLS
EXIT
```

I've no problems and everything works fine when executing the .bat file. But when this file is executed by a scheduled task the script is not able to read the emails neither collect the attachments.

I've checked the following:

- The task is running as Administrator
- Run with highest privileges checkbox is ticked.
- Last execution status of task is Correct.
- There is no related error in the Event Log Viewer.

What could be the cause?

Comment: Try to execute your script as an action performed on emails when outlook downloads them through the rules wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook, just like any other Office app, cannot be used in a service (that is what Task Scheduler is).

You can use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or a wrapper such as [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - any language), it's [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) family of objects can be used in a service.

You might also want to add a call to `Namepace.Logon`:

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
objNamespace.Logon
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6) 'Inbox
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll take a look at Extended MAPI.